# density trigonometric polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Good day,  I've been studying the next:[image]

My questions are two: In that notation, what is $C(T)$? Second, Which definition or density theorem is used to have $\left \| f-g \right \|_{p}< \frac{\varepsilon }{2}$? Thanks.

Comment: Continuous functions on $\mathbb T$? Is $\mathbb T$ the unit circle? Otherwise you should give more information on where this text is coming from.

Comment: yes, https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m201b/HW2sol201B_winter2011.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is defined/explained in professor's course:

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/pdfbook.html

Specifically in chapter 7:

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch7.pdf

To summarize in case the link dissapears:

$\mathbb T$ is the unit circle ($\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$) (corresponding to $2\pi$ periodic functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$.

$C(\mathbb T)$ is the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb T$ to $\mathbb C$

The density theorem is the one which states that $C(\mathbb T)$ is dense in $L_p(\mathbb T)$

Comment: but about density and  $\left \| f-g \right \|_{p}< \frac{\varepsilon }{2}$?

Comment: $\left \| f-g \right \|_{p}< \frac{\varepsilon }{2}$ for definition or some theorem?

Comment: $C(\mathbb T)$ is dense in $L_p(\mathbb T)$, so if $f\in L_p(\mathbb T)$ then there is a $g\in C(\mathbb T)$ such that $||f-g||_p<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by the definition of "dense"

Comment: but I see that the definition is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set

Comment: If you don't understand what "dense" is and you want to use the wikipedia definition, follow the below: In $L_p(\mathbb T)$ you have the distance $d(f,g)=||f-g||_p$. Then you take $B\left(f,\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$, which is the open ball of center $f$ and radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, as a neighborhood of $f$. By the definition of "dense" in your link, there is a function $g\in C(\mathbb T)$ such that $g\in B\left(f,\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$, which means $||f-g||_p<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$